# How to draw a automata state, circle containing a letter in it using java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to draw a circle with a letter in the center of it, which can be entered by the user. Below is the drawing function, but it's not working. (I have to draw a automata state )

```
private void doDrawingNew(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    String nam;
    float cx,cy;
    final Font f = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 18);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("InputDialog Example #1");
    for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
        GCircle obj = mylist.get(i);
        nam = obj.getName();

        if (nam == null) {
            nam = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What's your name?");
            obj.setName(nam);
        }
        cx=(float)obj.getX();
        cy=(float)obj.getY();
        cx=+40;
        cy=+40;
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 200, 0));
        g2d.fill(obj);
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.setFont(f);
        g2d.drawString(nam, cx, cy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "not working"...

Comment: This code seems a bit messy... And what is `mylist`? Are you trying to draw an automata that matches exactly the persons name?